# PHP, Object parameters with a loop

Tags: php, oop

What I want to do is fill the parameters with a loop.

Here the obj:

```
class Foo {
    public $foovar1
    public $foovar2
    public $foovar3

    public function __construct($foopara1, $foopara2, $foopara3) {
        $this->foovar1 = $foopara1;
        $this->foovar2 = $foopara2;
        $this->foovar3 = $foopara3;
    }
}
```

Now the magic:

```
<php?
    /*$foo = new Foo( HERE I WANT TO DO A LOOP );*/
    //But don't work...

    $foo = new Foo(
    for ($i=0; $i < 3; $i++) { 
        echo 'foopara.$i.,';
    }
    );
?>
```

This is the error: ( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'for' (T_FOR), expecting ')'

Comment: The syntax and logic are both so muderous

Comment: @devaldcool hahaha, my fault! I didn't explain well.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
class Foo {
    public $foovar1;
    public $foovar2;
    public $foovar3;

    public function __construct($foopara1, $foopara2, $foopara3) {
        $this->foovar1 = $foopara1;
        $this->foovar2 = $foopara2;
        $this->foovar3 = $foopara3;
    }
}

$class = new ReflectionClass('Foo');
$instance = $class->newInstanceArgs(range(0,2));
var_dump($instance);
/*
object(Foo)[2]
  public 'foovar1' => int 0
  public 'foovar2' => int 1
  public 'foovar3' => int 2
*/
```

- [ReflectionClass::newInstanceArgs](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.newinstanceargs.php)
- [range](http://pt2.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php)

Answer (score 1):

Please dont to this. It's not a good logic. if you want dynamic properties usable by loops, why not do it  like this?

```
class Foo {

    protected $vars = array();

    public __construct($vars){
        $this->vars = $vars;
    }

    // or even better: 
    public addVar($var){
        $this->var[] = $var;
    }

    public getVar($idx){
        return isset($this->var[$idx]) ? $this->var[$idx] : null;
    }

}

$Bar = new Foo();
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
    $Bar->addVar("something");
```

Or if you want a realy good solution, implement the ArrayAccess Interface and/or the IteratorInterface.

- http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php